# GPX file not opening in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gpx

QGIS used to allow me to load a GPX file into Qfield through "add vector layer". Now there is an option to add a GPX dataset but my file will not add.

Here's what I've tried. First I converted a Gpkg file into a GPX file with by "save as" and "GPS_USE_EXTENSION" as 'yes':

[image]

It didn't add the file to the map, so I tried to re-add the GPX file into the project to check that it was rendering. It didn't work by trying to add the GPS file as a vector. I tried the GPS option.  In the GPS option it asked me to choose waypoints, routes or tracks. I have tried all and none of them bring up the data. All give a data source error.

[image]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your GPX file encoding is UTF-8. Open your GPX file in a text editor such as NotePad++. Under the **Encoding** menu, select **UTF-8**, then **Save the file**.
[image]

or in Windows Powershell:

```
PS Get-Content .\mygpx.gpx | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 mygpx-utf8.gpx
```

Then try opening in QGIS again.